# Is Dharia a matriarchy?

Tags: dharian-affairs

I'm reading *The Third Daughter* by Susan Kaye Quinn (part of the [Dharian Affairs series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/127631-the-dharian-affairs-trilogy)), and I wonder if Dharia always has a queen, or is switching between Queens and Kings as main sovereign (or maybe a shared rulership between King and Queen). There are several mentions of the Queendom, but it might be because it is currently ruled by a Queen. So is Dharia a matriarchy?

Comment: I *think* so. I’ve never heard of Dharia referred to as anything but a matriarchy. This [blog post claims](http://www.fangsforthefantasy.com/2015/01/second-daughter-dharian-affairs-trilogy.html): “All of the world created by Susan Kaye Quinn are matriarchies.  Women are highly prized and men may only lead the country if there isn't a female heir.” but I don’t have a canon source to back that up.

Comment: @alexwlchan - Rather than re-reading the books, I thought it was easier to just ask the author

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:** I spoke to my new friend Susan Kaye Quinn [a little earlier](https://twitter.com/susankayequinn/status/617686692292526080) and posed her this question. She was kind enough to provide some additional detail about Dharian political life; in short, Dharia practices a form of [female-preference primogeniture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primogeniture#Matrilineal_primogeniture). If a female heir is born, they take precedence over any male heirs. If the sole living heir is male, they *can* ascend to the throne but for political purposes, they'd need to take a very strong female queen to act as [de-facto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_facto) [coregent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coregency).

<sub>*Please note that because the answer splits over multiple pages, I've taken the liberty of removing the line breaks.*</sub>

> **Q.** *Quick question, is Dharia a matriarchy? Can a man ascend to the throne if there's no [fe]male heir?*
>
> **SusanKayeQuinn:** *Well, there's definitely a king - Prince Malik wants to be one. but he needs a Queen for legitimacy. In this case the
>   king is the most-direct descendent, so he would be the defacto ruler
>   (with the Queen secondary, by marriage).*
>
> *But if a daughter is directly available? She would always be First Daughter... and then Queen. You'll see this in Second Daughter, where
>   the princes of Samir are the heir apparents. but need a Queen to legit
>   their rule*

<s>The implication from [this interview](http://www.melaniekarsak.com/2014/02/steampunk-with-heart-steampunk-is.html) with the author is that Dharian society practice [Matrilineal Succession](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrilineal_succession) (e.g. that if there's a daughter, they take priority over a male heir):</s>

Comment: Wow, connections. I'm impressed. Direct word of the author beats everything I guess, so I can accept directly instead of waiting for more answers.